# Can't select curve control points

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm sure I'll embarrass myself here, but I can't seem to select individual control points on a curve in edit mode.  Not by box select, not by circle select, not by clicking on them.  In box select mode, for example, Blender draws the affordance for the box, but nothing gets selected.

Select All (A) works.  Deselect all (A, A) works.  Editing a mesh object works normally.  I can delete the curve, make sure nothing is selected, add another, and I get the same problem.  I can add a mesh object and edit it normally.  The problem only seems to affect curves of all types, and only in this file.

This is on 2.92.0 on Win10.  New files and other recent saves are not affected.

Ideas?

Comment: Can you add a photo so we can see if anything is off?

Comment: As soon as I get back to the system, I'll record the response of the various select tools.

Comment: Check "Proportional Edit", make sure it's not enabled.

Comment: please share the file here: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are in the "Modeling" tab (at the top) and not in layout (or anywhere else).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to select an action tool from the tool bar before you can select the control points for a bezier curve. The transform tool works.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found that if your viewport has somehow been clipped in any way, this can cause you to be unable to select control points in some circumstances. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to unclip the viewport.